# Using @Model from SwiftData in a class how can I use a struct as a var type

Tags: swift, swift-data

I have struct I wish to use inside a `@Model` class.

```swift
struct dimUnits {
    var now: UInt
    var prev: UInt
}

@Model
class SurfaceJob: Identifiable {
    public var id: UUID?
    var timestamp: Date
    var name: String
    var units: UInt
    var xSize: Double
    var ySize: Double
    var xyUnits: dimUnits
```

The compiler complains `No exact matches in call to instance method 'setValue'` and displays

```swift
{
    @storageRestrictions(accesses: _$backingData, initializes: _xyUnits)
        init(initialValue) {
                    _$backingData.setValue(forKey: \.xyUnits, to: initialValue)
                    _xyUnits = _SwiftDataNoType()
        }

    get {
                    _$observationRegistrar.access(self, keyPath: \.xyUnits)
                    return self.getValue(forKey: \.xyUnits)
        }

    set {
                    _$observationRegistrar.withMutation(of: self, keyPath: \.xyUnits) {
                            self.setValue(forKey: \.xyUnits, to: newValue)
                    }
        }
}
```

Which would seem to indicate there is no `setValue` defined for the type.

I tried creating one but am not having any luck.

So how can you use a struct as a data type in a SwiftData model class?

The answer is to make the struct confom to `Codable1`.

```swift
struct dimUnits: Codable {
    var now: UInt
    var prev: UInt
}
```

Comment: The struct needs to conform to Codable

Comment: Changing code to reflect solution

Comment: Don't put the solution in the Question field. That just defaces and confuses the question. Leave the question as it was, so it's clear what the problem was to begin with. If you have a solution, you can put it in the Answer field, or if the problem was trivially solved, just delete the question.

Comment: What @matt says. Somebody (you can do it yourself) should turn the first comment into an answer with a bit of (in this case) trivial code and then you should accept it. That way, other people who have the same question can find it and the answers easily.

Comment: @JeremyP Or possibly the "solution" is too basic and trivial an observation to need a QA at all. The error message wasn't very helpful, true, but use of SwiftData in the first place sort of presupposes knowing this.

Comment: @matt Using any framework or language presupposes a lot. Where do you draw the line? For example, my Objective-C rep includes a lot of points answering questions about retain and release and when you should use them all of which arguable Objective-C presupposes you know.

Comment: Well, it's up the OP.

Comment: I do not see any way to mark @JoakimDanielson answer as the solution.

Comment: You can’t so either you post an answer or I do.